# node.js javascript var available in res.render()'s target

Tags: javascript, extjs, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a variable (eventually to be replaced by more complex json selected from the database) accessible to client-side javascript.  I wanted to load it when the page is rendered instead of an ajax call and its not going to be rendered via a template like ejs (I want to pass the data to an extjs store for a combobox).  So I have a standart response I render:

```
function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html', {foo: ['a','b']});
}
```

and a blank html page I want to access foo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript>
console.log(foo);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas?  I've thought of maybe writing the whole html page via res.send() (which has a few more things than the example above) but that seems like such a workaround for something that should be obvious to do...

Comment: What if JavaScript is disabled? Encode server side information in HTML.

Comment: The app is using Sencha Touch (which requires webkit).  It would eventually use phonegap and make its way to android and apple markets, so yes that would be a very bad idea if the app was meant for wide coverage (such as yahoo.com would be unhappy to miss out on the 2% users that don't use javascript), but the app is targeted for a more specific audience.

Comment: @qooleot It's not about the user %. It's about seperation of concerns. What your doing is simply bad practice.

Comment: Ok thanks, and definitely I don't want to be stubborn and 'force' variables into client-side javascript using the wrong tool (ejs appears to be meant for html templates).  The ultimate question is how do I get json from the node server to the client without having to load the page then have it make an ajax call back to the server)?

It seems like such a trivial thing for PHP to just inject some JSON into a page for client-side javascript to consume, but I'm struggling to find a node example (I see pushing the data via an ajax call, socket, returning back json via a RESTful API, etc).

Comment: @qooleot PHP teaches you bad practices (injecting JSON into a page). Use semantic HTML and get a static javascript file to enhance your html page. If you really need to load more data use ajax to talk to a REST web service.

Comment: Yes certainly PHP allows for spaghetti code, bad practices, etc.  I'd argue bad fundamentals and understanding of design patterns are probably worse than a language that allows unstructured code - but we're in agreement. I do use progressive markup with jquery for several projects, but for this specific task I'm using sencha touch and it doesn't really doesn't support rendering from existing markup or at least would be slow.  Also, AJAX calls would be harmless on the desktop but it appears an extra trip to the server to grab JSON I already have seems inefficient.  Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I would still employ minimal html page and then having client side template rendering fueled by requesting json data for your rendering from a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same array `foo` in your question above, here are a couple ways you could do this.

This one uses an EJS filter to write an array literal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = ['<%=: foo | join:"', '" %>'];
</script>
```

This one encodes it as JSON, to later be parsed by your client-side javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// note the "-" instead of "=" on the opening tag; it avoids escaping HTML entities
var fooJSON = '<%-JSON.stringify(foo)%>';
</script>
```

IIRC, ExtJS can handle JSON directly as its data. If not, then you could use its JSON parser first and then hand it a local variable. If you weren't using ExtJS, you could use this to parse on the client: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

If you choose to encode it as JSON, it would make it also make it easier to later switch back to AJAX for retrieving your data. In some cases, that would have an advantage. The page could load and display some data, along with a busy icon over the element for which you're loading data.

This isn't to say there's anything inherently wrong with including all the data in the original request. It's just that sticking with JSON gives you the flexibility to choose later.

Answer (score 1):

In EJS the following should work

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  console.log( <%= foo %>);
</script>
```

I do recommend against dynamically generating JavaScript though as it breaks seperation of concerns and forces JavaScript to be on.

**Edit:**

Turns out the above doesn't work nicely for arrays. So simply encode your data in semantic HTML. Then *enhance* it with JavaScript. If the JavaScript must get data then store it somewhere more sensible like the cookie or retrieve it through ajax.

Comment: The issue with that is if I define 'foo' like I did above, then I get back:

"a,b"

which isn't formatted like the array of strings (its missing quotes around that text) that I set up.

Comment: Why would you recommend against dynamically generating javascript? If the application is ExtJS anyway, then the application won't run without javascript anyway.

Comment: @BlackTiger because dynamically generated javascript leads to the tag soup we had in the PHP3/ASP days. Use static packaged, minified, bundled and compressed javascript. Your view/template should only be responsible for dynamically generated HTML. (CSS should also be static)

Comment: Sure, but then you could have a page that has to load a lot of database information performing several ajax requests thus making the page load significantly slower. I suppose like with anything else you have to weigh the benefits and disadvantages for your specific use.

Comment: Yes you could. but that's only a side-effect from bad design. If you employed progressive enhancement and Unobtrusive JavaScript techniques then this would not be the case.